# nuget.telerik - unable to load the service index for source

Tags: xamarin, nuget, telerik

`Nuget package` is not getting downloaded for `Telerik.UI.for.Xamarin`. When I select `Package Source` Telerik Nuget, getting an error

```
 Unable to find package Telerik.UI.for.Xamarin with version (>= 2019.2.619.1)
 Found 1 version(s) in nuget.org [ Nearest version: 2015.3.1202 ]   

 [Telerik Nuget] Unable to load the service index for source https://nuget.telerik.com/v3/index.json.
 Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).
```

I have added credentials in `APPDATA`'s `nuget.config` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
   <clear />
  <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
  <add key="Telerik Nuget" value="https://nuget.telerik.com/v3/index.json" />
</packageSources>
 <packageSourceCredentials>
    <telerik>
      <add key="Username" value="*****" />
      <add key="ClearTextPassword" value="*****" />
   </telerik>
 </packageSourceCredentials>
</configuration>
```

Please check below screenshot for more information

[image]

I have also added `https://nuget.telerik.com/nuget` url and credentials in `Window cre manager` manually.

How can I fix this issue ?

Comment: `401 (Unauthorized)` seems like a pretty big clue.  Double-check your credentials.  It doesn't look like the key value you use in the credentials matches the key in the packagesources node

Comment: @Jason - You are right, my credentials was incorrect. I was ignoring case sensitivity. Its working now.

Comment: I had a similar issue where I had to escape an `&` in the XML for the password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The given error is happening due to wrong combination of username and password.

```
Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized)
```

Password is case sensitive.